# Changing my program so that there's a combobox to change between rectangles and circles

Tags: javafx

I have a code that creates multiple random rectangles. I need to add a combobox that changes the shape created and I don't know how to go about it. Sorry if this code is a mess to read. I don't know much about javafx.

```
public class ModernArtPt2 extends Application {
    //Array of names
    private String[] shapeName = {"Circle", "Square"};
    private ComboBox<String> cbo = new ComboBox<>();
    private DescriptionPane descriptionPane = new DescriptionPane();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Random rand = new Random();

// Set the first shape for display
        setDisplay(0);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        BorderPane paneForComboBox = new BorderPane();
        paneForComboBox.setLeft(new Label("Select a shape: "));
        paneForComboBox.setCenter(cbo);
        pane.setTop(paneForComboBox);

        ObservableList<String> items =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(shapeName);
        cbo.getItems().addAll(items);
        //pane.setCenter(descriptionPane);
        // Display the selected country
        cbo.setOnAction(e -> setDisplay(items.indexOf(cbo.getValue())));
// Create 50 rectangles
        Group group = new Group();
        for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.setX(rand.nextInt(600));
            r.setY(rand.nextInt(300));
            r.setWidth(rand.nextInt(90) + 10);
            r.setHeight(rand.nextInt(90) + 10);
            r.setFill(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()));
            r.setOpacity(Math.random());
            group.getChildren().add(r);
        }

// Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(group), 600, 300); //New Scene
        primaryStage.setTitle("Modern Art"); // Stage Title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    public void setDisplay(int index) {
        descriptionPane.setTitle(shapeName[index]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what can be done. As said it is just an example, some improvements can be done according the number of shapes the user can select and in the error management.

```
/**
 * @since 20180320
 */
public class ModernArtPt2 extends Application {

   public enum MyShape {

      RECT("Rectangle"), CIRCLE("Circle");

      /** Name of the shape. */
      private String name;

      /**
       * Constructor.
       * 
       * @param pName
       *           the name of the shape.
       */
      private MyShape(String pName) {
         name = pName;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return name;
      }

      /**
       * @return {@code true} if the selected shape is rectangle, {@code false} otherwise.
       */
      public boolean isRectSelected() {
         return "Rectangle".equals(this.toString());
      }
   }

   private ComboBox<MyShape> cbo = new ComboBox<>();

   private Group group;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

      BorderPane paneForComboBox = new BorderPane();
      paneForComboBox.setLeft(new Label("Select a shape: "));
      paneForComboBox.setCenter(cbo);
      pane.setTop(paneForComboBox);

      // Create 50 rectangles
      group = initializeRandomShape();
      pane.setCenter(group);

      ObservableList<MyShape> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(MyShape.values());
      cbo.getItems().addAll(items);
      // pane.setCenter(descriptionPane);
      // Display the selected country
      cbo.setOnAction(e -> changeDisplay(cbo.getValue()));
      cbo.getSelectionModel().select(0);

      // Create a scene and place it in the stage
      Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 300); // New Scene
      primaryStage.setTitle("Modern Art"); // Stage Title
      primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in stage
      primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
   }

   /**
    * Creates a group and return it with 50 random shapes.
    * 
    * @return a {@link Group} populated with 50 random shapes.
    */
   private Group initializeRandomShape() {
      Random rand = new Random();
      // Create 50 rectangles
      Group group = new Group();
      for(int i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
         Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
         r.setX(rand.nextInt(600));
         r.setY(rand.nextInt(300));
         r.setWidth(rand.nextInt(90) + 10);
         r.setHeight(rand.nextInt(90) + 10);
         r.setFill(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()));
         r.setOpacity(Math.random());
         group.getChildren().add(r);
      }

      return group;
   }

   /**
    * @param pShape
    */
   public void changeDisplay(MyShape pShape) {
      Shape lSelectedShape = getSelectedShape(pShape.toString());

      if(lSelectedShape != null) {
         List<Shape> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();
         for(Node node: group.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            if(Shape.class.isInstance(node)) {
               Shape lShape = changeShape(Shape.class.cast(node), pShape.isRectSelected());
               if(lShape != null) {
                  nodeList.add(lShape);
               }
            }
         }
         if(nodeList.size() > 0) {
            group.getChildren().clear();
            group.getChildren().addAll(nodeList);
         } else {
            // LOG an error with a logger.
            System.out.println("An error occurs.");
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * Creates a shape according to the provided String.<br>
    * Enumerate could be used with String and Shape associated, it will be cleaner.
    * 
    * @param pString
    *           a {@link String} representing the selected shape by the user.
    * @return the {@link Shape} associated to the provided {@link String}.
    */
   private Shape getSelectedShape(String pString) {
      Shape lSelectedShape = null;
      if("Circle".equals(pString)) {
         lSelectedShape = new Arc();
      } else if("Rectangle".equals(pString)) {
         lSelectedShape = new Rectangle();
      }
      return lSelectedShape;
   }

   /**
    * Changes the provided shape by the new one (also provided).<br>
    * It actually extract the useful data of the current shape in order to parameterized the new
    * shape. If the new one is equal to the previous one, does nothing.
    * 
    * @param pCurrentShape
    *           the current shape to change.
    * @param pIsRectangleSelected
    *           a {@link Boolean} indicating if the selected shape by user is a rectangle.
    * @return the new created shape.
    */
   private Shape changeShape(Shape pCurrentShape, boolean pIsRectangleSelected) {
      Shape lShape;
      if(Rectangle.class.isInstance(pCurrentShape) && !pIsRectangleSelected) {
         Rectangle rect = Rectangle.class.cast(pCurrentShape);
         double centerX = rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2;
         double centerY = rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2;
         Arc arc = new Arc(centerX, centerY, rect.getWidth() / 2, rect.getHeight() / 2, 0, 360.0);
         arc.setFill(rect.getFill());
         arc.setOpacity(rect.getOpacity());
         lShape = arc;
      } else if(Arc.class.isInstance(pCurrentShape) && pIsRectangleSelected) {
         Arc lArc = Arc.class.cast(pCurrentShape);
         double lX = lArc.getCenterX() - lArc.getRadiusX();
         double lY = lArc.getCenterY() - lArc.getRadiusY();
         Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(lX, lY, 2 * lArc.getRadiusX(), 2 * lArc.getRadiusY());
         rect.setFill(lArc.getFill());
         rect.setOpacity(lArc.getOpacity());
         lShape = rect;
      } else {
         lShape = null;
         System.out.println("Not a rectangle : " + pCurrentShape);
      }
      return lShape;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```